# Télécharger, one word in french , two correspondent words in English?

Tags: traduction

I am creating a menu for a website and the translation agency has send me the french translations for it.
I am now struggling with the fact that the menu items are too long. 
Submit CV has been translated by "Téléchargez votre CV"

My question would be "Télécharger" can be "download" as well as "upload"? 
We want to mean upload/submit in this particular case. I am not sure if this is a correct translation.

Comment: Dans ce cas, le terme "Envoyer" semble le plus proche du sens voulu. Dans la question mise en lien, les termes proposé sont beaucoup plus verbeux et formels...